# Labels do not fit correctly on Pie

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In effort to learn D3.js, I took [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/clayzermk1/4290070) and made a plunker out of it
http://plnkr.co/edit/ynWB0GznvrMMRmqkaqaA?p=preview

**Problem?**

The data doesn't fit correctly and you can see that data is incomplete

How shall I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that your labels are incorrect. So change this:

```
  .text(function(d) { 
    return 'd.data.age'; });
```

to this:

```
  .text(function(d) { 
    return d.data.age; });
```

and you'll get the correct labels.

Second, the labels are getting cut off. This appears to be to do with the sizes specified for the pie chart. You can either increase the width specified (looks fine at 360 say):

```
var width = 360,
height = 300,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
```

Or bring the labels in closer to the graph:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + ( (radius -50) * Math.sin( ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2) + d.startAngle ) ) + "," + ( -1 * (radius - 50) * Math.cos( ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2) + d.startAngle ) ) + ")"; })
```

Where it says `radius - x` determines how close or far the labels will appear to the graph. The bigger x is, the closer they will be.